# Solve using substitution method solve $T(n) = T(n-1) + n$ by guessing $O(n)$

Tags: recursion, recursive-algorithms

I'm still learning the substitution method and I'm a bit confused on how to find out whether my guess in fact correct or not

Here's what I did so far:

> Induction goal: $T(n) ≤ cn$
> Induction hypothesis: $T(n-1) ≤ c(n-1)$

\begin{split}
T(n)&=T(n−1)+n≤c(n−1)+n \\ 
&=cn−c+n≤cn
\end{split}
$$c \geq n$$

I don't know what I'm supposed to conclude from this, or from most substitutions I do.

Comment: In this case you don't need induction, this is a telescopic sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that $c$ must be constant but find a contradictory inequality, i.e., $c \geq n$. Hence, your assumption has been disputed. Thus, your guess is not correct.

To find the final value, you can easily do it by substitution like the following:

$$
T(n) = T(n-1) + n = T(n-2) + (n-1) + n
$$

Now, by induction, we can show that the following if we assume that $T(1) =  1$:

$$
T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i
$$

Therefore, $T(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$ and consequently $T(n) \in O(n^2)$.

Comment: This makes sense but I'm a bit lost on something. So, since c is a constant ,how does it contradict to the inequality? is it because n is variable? Cause there are some questions in my textbook where we find relations where c >= 1/(2-1/n) and we assume that for any n >= 1, it works

Comment: @NayaCruiser yes. as $c > n$ means $c = \Omega(n)$. Hence it cannot be a constant. Because a constant is in $\Theta(1)$. You should consider the case when $n \to \infty$.